# Company App distribution without Company Hub app

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8

We have developed a private WP8 application, and we have registered company account on Windows Phone Dev Center.

The next step is the development of "Company Hub app" which will take care for installation and available updates.

Since we have only one application, I think there is no need to develop "Company Hub app".

Is it possible that the application itself check for any available updates? (We plan to develop webservice for upgrades distribution).

Can I do the following:

- Application Check for updates
- If so, take the installation of a new version
- The application installs a new version of itself. (If this is possible, how to do it?)

So far I have managed to find only examples with  "Company Hub app"

Thanks

Selvir K

Answer (score 1):

> So far I have managed to find only examples with "Company Hub app"

That's because it's the only way.

To deploy applications on Windows Phone, you have three options:

- Using the marketplace
- Using the company hub: you get the benefits of the marketplace, but inside of your company network
- Using the XAP deploy tool. The phone needs to be developer unlocked (it's a free operation now), there is a limit to the number of apps you can deploy this way on a phone, and you lose the benefits of automatic updates

One alternative way could be to publish an app on the marketplace and mark it as hidden. Only people who have the direct link to your app will be able to download it. Still, if the link to the app is somehow leaked outside of the company, you'll have no way to control who installs the app. So don't do that for critical/confidential applications.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Does this mean that there is no way that the Company Hub App upgrade  itself to the new version?

Comment: @SelvirK From the company hub app, it should be possible to silently install an update. At least, the MSDN documentation doesn't indicate that any user interaction is required: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207248(v=vs.105).aspx . But afaik the app you pushed with the company hub cannot update itself, it's the company hub that will take care of all the updates

Comment: If I develop a Company Hub app, it will have the ability to install new Company applications and upgrade the installed Company applications to the new version.

How to upgrade Company Hub app to the new version?
Can this be done automatically, or user must manually take a new version of Company Hub app?

Comment: @SelvirK That's a good question. If you use Intune, I believe you can push the update to the users http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884158.aspx If you manually build the company hub, then it's very likely that it has to be updated manually (by sending the XAP to users), but unfortunately I'm not completely sure

Answer (score 0):

I am in the exact same boat. We are working on our fist wp8 app and do not want a company hub.

I found if you use InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync(String, Uri) method within your app this will go to our website and download\install the xap file very easily. Of course once executed it appears to close your app so it can reinstall but for now this works fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to see this post as I just finished developing a Windows Phone 8 app for a client, which was in a similar situation. I found publishing to Windows Phone Beta Store severed them the best for the moment for the main reasons below.

- The distribution is totally in client's control. The apps in beta
  store do not appear nor can be searched in public store. Client just need to send
  emails with the app link to its employees. Only the people with the
  Windows Accounts added into the tester's list are allowed to download
  and install it. Up to 10,000 testers are allowed which is more than
  enough for most of the business.
- It is much easier to publish it in beta store compared to it is in the
  public one. It does not require strict certification as it does in public store. It is an automatic process and only takes a few hours compared to up to two weeks in public store.
- From the end users point of view, after it is installed there is no difference. It is the same app and it does not expire (as of today).